# Evaluating a Gaussian Fit

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'd like to know ways to determine how well a Gaussian function is fitting my data.

Here are a few plots I've been testing methods against. Currently, I'm just using the RMSE of the fit versus the sample (red is fit, blue is sample).

For instance, here are 2 good fits:

[image: Good Fit]

[image]

And here are 2 terrible fits that should be flagged as bad data:

[image]
[image]

In general, I'm looking for suggestions of additional metrics to measure the goodness of fit. Additionally, as you can see in the second 'good' fit, there can sometimes be other peaks outside the data. Currently, these are penalized by the RSME method, though they should not be.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for suggestions of additional metrics to measure the goodness of fit.

The one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test would be a good starting point.

I'd suggest the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) as an introduction.

The test is available in SciPy as [`scipy.stats.kstest`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html). The function computes and returns both the KS test statistic and the [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value).

Comment: The KS statistic may be useful to quantify just how non-Gaussian the data are, but the test is useless: it is known a priori that the distribution is not Gaussian, so a test could only tell you what you already know.

Comment: The distribution is Gaussian -- it's whether or not the experimental data is Gaussian or noise (where I'm just integrating over garbage). It's mass spectrometry data so there are hundreds of thousands of spectra to do this for. KS might be useful to evaluate whether my data came from the derived normal distribution, but it still suffers from outliers... Maybe I can just limit myself to +- 2 deviations for my KS-statistic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try quantile-quantile (qq) plots using [probplot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html) from stats:

```
import pylab
from stats import probplot

plot = probplot(data, dist='norm', plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

> Calculate quantiles for a probability plot, and optionally show the
>   plot.
>
> Generates a probability plot of sample data against the quantiles of a
>   specified theoretical distribution (the normal distribution by
>   default). probplot optionally calculates a best-fit line for the data
>   and plots the results using Matplotlib or a given plot function.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of evaluating a good fit, but most of them are not robust to outliers.

There is `MSE` - Mean squared error, which you already know, and `RMSE` which is the root of it.

But you can also measure it using `MAE` - Mean Absolute Error and `MAPE` - Mean absolute percentage error.

Also, there is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test which is far more complex and you would probably need a library to do that, while `MAE`, `MAPE` and `MSE` you can implement yourself quiet easily.

<sub>(If you are dealing with unsupervised data and/or classification, which is not your case apparently, `ROC` curves and confusion matrix are also accuracy metrics.)</sub>